# Need help in formulating linear program

Tags: linear-programming

> [image][image]

---

Edit: updated my solution for linear programming

Can anyone explain the following passage?

> Both semiconductors and power generation industries also want to buy as many of the remaining units as possible

How should I formulate the linear program with that?

Comment: Welcome to OR.SE. I recommended you try to formulate your problem, even in the simplest form, and then ask your question again. :)

Comment: @A.Omidi Hi sir, i've updated my solution, would like to ask you to check for it

Comment: You don't need to add variables $a$ and $b$ to your model. When it is written "at least", define your constraint as $\geq 30$ (constraint 6), and when there is no minimum quantity, define it as $\geq 0$ (constraint 7) The model then optimizes the quantities.